# How can we run loop inside feature file to get data from one api and pass in another api

Tags: cucumber, karate

I am trying to run a loop inside feature file to iterate array of json objects.

```
    Feature: Get Tariffs information

  Background:
    Given url baseURL
    And def auth = Java.type('com.llda.utilities.AuthUtil')
    
    And path '/api/Sites'
    And def expectedResponseSites = read('classpath:/Podium/Sites/Sites.json')
    When method get
    Then status 200
    
    And def SiteHk = $[0].siteHK
    * print SiteHk
     
   Scenario: Verify response without bearer token
     * def fun = function(i){ call read('TariffsHelper.feature@BaseScenarioTariffHelper'){siteHKId: #($[i].siteHK)} }
        * def foo = karate.repeat(response.length, fun)
```

Here "siteHK" is a parameter which I need to pass in second api.
"SiteHk" is coming in objects of array in first api. hence I need to validate the second api which multiple set of dynamic data which is coming in response for first api.

Second api is getting called from "TariffsHelper.feature" file, which I am calling from another feature file.
I have used karate loop to iterate this but Getting following error when try to run this program:

```
>>> failed features:
>>>> js failed:
01: (function(i){ call read('TariffsHelper.feature@BaseScenarioTariffHelper'){siteHKId: #($[i].siteHK)} })
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: SyntaxError: Unnamed:1:19 Expected ; but found read
(function(i){ call read('TariffsHelper.feature@BaseScenarioTariffHelper'){siteHKId: #($[i].siteHK)} })
```

Please let know if there is any another approach to iterate dynamic value from one api and pass in second api.

** I have investigated the same to get this done though java or java script code but did not find any solution to call feature file inside java or java script function.

Comment: you are not looking hard enough. see linked answer. if still stuck, follow this process please: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue